# Get HTML tag contents using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Below is my sample html code,

```
 <section class="well well-2" style="background-color:#eee">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                     <h3 style="color:#CC0000">Car Bumper</h3>
                     <p>Entrusting upon credible vendors for high-grade raw materials, we manufacture and supply premium quality Car Bumper.</p>
                     <a href="car_bumper.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow-green">...More</a>        
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                     <h3 style="color:#CC0000">Car Body Kits</h3>
                     <p>Enriched with a vast industry experience, we are capable of manufacturing and supplying best quality Car Body Kits.</p>
                     <a href="car_bodykitss.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow-green">...More</a>        
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                     <h3 style="color:#CC0000">Car Alteration</h3>
                     <p>We are a credible name that is occupied in the business of manufacturing and supplying of best quality Car Modification Kit.</p>
                     <a href="car_alteration.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow-green">...More</a>        
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                     <h3 style="color:#CC0000">Car Styling Kits</h3>
                     <p>We are one among the prominent manufacturers and suppliers of a wide array of Car Styling kits with perfect finishing.</p>
                     <a href="car_stylingkit.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow-green">...More</a>        
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                     <h3 style="color:#CC0000">Car Painting Services</h3>
                     <p>Painting requires special expertises, we paint cars , which offers ultraviolet blockers in the clear coat.</p>
                     <a href="car_painting.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow-green">...More</a>        
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                     <h3 style="color:#CC0000">Car Spoiler</h3>
                     <p>We are listed at the acme for manufacturing and supplying an ample range of best quality Car Spoilers.</p>
                     <a href="car_spoiler.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow-green">...More</a>        
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </section>
```

From this Page of content I retrieve tag content via below PHP code,

```
 <?php
  include('simple_html_dom.php');
  $filename='index.php';
  $dom = file_get_contents($filename);
  $html = file_get_html($filename);
$h3=array();
$p=array();
$tags = get_meta_tags($filename);
foreach($html->find('h3') as $element) { ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">H3</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="h3[]" id="h3[]" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php  $k++; foreach($html->find('p') as $element) {?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Paragraph</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p1[]" name="p1[]" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } $o++;
?>
```

So that It will retrieve content like below screen

[image]

But I Want the result in order of h3 and its paragraph and next its h3 and its paragraph how can I do with this.I dont know And I tried in many way anyone please help me solve this prblm.Thanks in advance.

Comment: An easy solution is to just loop through as you are doing except store the html in an array using output buffering, then imploding (or looping again) over the new array to output the compiled content to browser.

Comment: Can u show it in simple code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$filename='index.php';
$html = file_get_html($filename);

$h3 = array();
foreach ($html->find('h3') as $element) {
    $h3[] = $element->innertext;
}

$p = array();
foreach ($html->find('p') as $element) {
    $p[] = $element->innertext;
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($h3); $i++) {
    ?>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label class = "control-label col-sm-2" for = "pwd">H3</label>
        <div class = "col-sm-10">
            <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "h3[$i]" id = "h3[$i]" value = "<?php echo $h3[$i] ?>">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Paragraph</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p[$i]" name="p[$i]" value="<?php echo $p[$i] ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Ya Murthy its working correctly but similarly how can I get all codes dynamically like if index has one h1 tag below one paragraph then h2 tag with 2 para and h3 tag with 4 paragraph how Can we get all tags

Comment: I mean paragraph which defined under h1 similarly how can we differentiate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using separate variables for the 2 loops? I see you're using `$element` for both loops that just seems inappropriate.